# Error in Java EE project

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I uninstalled the jdk and again installed it. And when Java EE projects are opened in eclipse, they all are showing errors on each and every line, which projects were created before and was working fine.

Plz tell me what is the error or how to build the path for it

Comment: make sure eclispe is looking in the right place for your jdk

Comment: Did you set the classpath in eclipse after installing jdk?

Comment: try to create a new project, and see what happens. One possible reason is that the path to jdk folder has changed.

Comment: The normal and more useful approach is that you tell us the errors, instead of the other way around. Which errors are you getting?

Comment: @Ami classpath is set in environment variable.How to set the classpath in eclipse

Comment: @erik pragt error is to configure buildpath

Comment: Did any of the solutions below work for you?

Comment: ya, answer given by ppterka worked

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to remove and re-add the JRE(JDK) from the build path? Right click on the projects->Java build path->Add library.

Be sure to point to the right jdk directory.

Answer (score 1):

Open **Window menu**, then select **Preferences**

In the tree open  **Java**, select **Installed JREs**, then **Add...** the new one, and delete the invalid one.

This sets Eclipse's default values, however, you might have to check the project specific settings by right clilcking on the project, selecting **Properties**, and

- **Run/Debug settings** - all run/debug settings can have different JRE set up on the JRE tab
- **Java Build Path** on the  **Libraries** tab: delete invalid JRE, add new one using **Add Library...** and selecting JRE System Library

Also, while you're at it, be sure to check

- **PATH** environment variable, to have the valid path
- **JAVA_HOME** environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Preferences, select Java -> Installed JREs, make sure you have added your new java installation here.

Right click on your project, select Properties, select Build Path -> Libraries, remove and add JRE System Library. Also, check if you have enabled any project specific configurations (like compiler version, etc) for Java Compiler in project Properties, if yes, update that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar situations.

Make sure:

- Your JRE settings is pointing to the JDK.
- Go to your project properties and make sure it's using the right java version.
- Check there are no build path errors, and make sure all dependent jars can use the new java version.

If it still doesn't work, it may be Eclipse playing up.

Try to reset the project configurations and code by closing the projects, open them again, run a F5 refresh on the project clean it and rebuilt it.